# Is using an HTML Form the ONLY way to post a $var to $PHP_SELF?

Tags: php

IS there a way to post a `$var` to `$PHP_SELF` so that I can use it further down the script?

After 2 hours reading dozens of questions which helpfully appear in the sidebar to the right,
it became apparent that they pretty much all assume an HTML Form has been / will be
activated.

But psuedo~code of what I need looks more like this:

```
 <  php
 $someVariable=y;
 $otherVar=X;

 // and the usual setup for accessing the `$_POST` of php:
 $HokeyDino=`$_POST`["SendOFF"];
 $SendOFF=101;

// etc. and then come to a point where I need the script to just automatically post a value

[  the lack of knowledge ]

// which if I had tha codez!
// would permit the use of that $var,  $HokeyDino ...

 if($HokeyDino==100){
 // do stuff
    }
```

I don't like looking foolish, but gotta ask away, because I figure I have missed learning some elementary aspect of programming, being self-taught so far, but not knowing what might be lacking makes it hard to go look productively.

Thanks very much!

EDIT //  Clarification.

Wow, this is amazing.  half an hour, 24 people reading the question.  Blows my mind.

Right.  What I have gotten done so far to give more background:

A php script which uses fopen to create on the fly another php / html page, and all the
code on the *Authouring* originating script, to write (a+) to the newly created temp page, the whole thing.

From a loop on the authouring page, I have code for retrieving POSTS I send TO that temp page, and that code gets written to a very temp page... then I cause the first part of the page to be written, to get placed on the Temp page, by put`_`contents etc.,

Next, from another loop on the Authouring page, I write code which item by item matches the things which were included in the `< head >` of the Temp page.

Anyhow, without graphics, it's a bit tough to explain.  What I have at the point I have gotten to so far, is the newly created/assemble Temporary page, can be accessed as a WebPage,, and a button click on it, will successfully POST a value back to the originating/Authouring script.

Here's the tricky part:  There isn't any way I was able to devise, to dynamically create code ON THE AUTHOURING page, to recieve POSTS from the Temp Page.

But I realized that if, in the Loops on the Authoring Page, I was able to `$PHP SELF` post a
string which would be the code for creating `a *  $Var = $ POST;` to catch the values from button clicks on the TEMP page, it would work.

Critical, is that the Authoring Page, doesn't know how many buttons will be made over on the Temp Page ~ that depends on the number of items in the database, which the loops are reading and translating into code which builds the Temp Page.

So, there is no way to hard~code, on the Authouring Page, all possible code for recieving posts, but I could use one Universal `$Var= $ POST[ X ]` if I could generate it on the fly in the loop, on the Authoring Page.

Hence the need to write code which will `$SELF POST`, and have it triggered just by normal programme flow, and not the click of a button in a form.

Hmm....  clear as mud yet?   :)  the question still is pretty straight foreward.

Cheers!

```
       ////  Loop
        Create  CViewerTemp
           read DB and manipulate data
             Loop B
           create, and write to VeryTempHead page
                    code which creates the top of CViewer, HEAD items
           create, and write to VeryTempBody page
                    code which will work there, items one by one matching head items
              end Loop B
        Write code which is 1ne time only stuff, to begin CViewer.
           then transfer the stuff from VeryTempHead page, into CViewer, kill
           VeryTempHead
           then transfer the stuff from VeryTempBody to CViewer, kill Very Temp Body.
        Open CTempViwer, click on a Button, a value gets posted to Authouring Page.

         Authouring Page doesn't recieve anything, no code to do so exists  [YET! :)]
```

Comment: Mmm, not sure what your end goal with this is. Where does `SendOFF` come from, is it user input?

Comment: "and then come to a point where I need the script to just automatically post a value" --- where to post a value? To another site?

Comment: you will not get any help with this wall of text

Comment: I think you need to find a good php Tutorial site where you can get your basics done - this will make it much easier for you.

Comment: Forget everything you have put above.  Explain in 2 sentences what you want to do.

Comment: I specified I am not using an HTML form.  hidden field ~ not applicable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to create data on the fly, but not from $_POST, you can just populate $_POST from any other source like this:

```
<?php
// some calculations
$_POST['my_var'] = $some_calculated_stuff;

// later in your code

if(isset($_POST['my_var'])) {
 // works as if it had been posted
}

?>
```

Is this what you're looking to do?

It's a bit hard to follow, so I'll suggest another potential:

Have you taken a look at [cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/curl.examples.php)?

Comment: Are you serious?  It is that simple?  HA! I was afraid it would be.

Comment: I'll try that now; take half an hour or so.

Comment: @MyStream Thanks a whole bunch; it was not being aware of how to use $ POST without the HTML form, that was the sticking point.  PHP is a huge, immense language and it is odd, but in 200,000 lines of php in a number of different projects, I'd never needed that.  Less than 20 lines of code, knowing how to post without the HTML form, makes 1200 lines of code beautiful instead of a smouldering heap.  Thanks again!

Comment: My Pleasure =) - perhaps update your question with some additional solution details for felloe SO users to understand what worked and why? - Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean hidden input fields. You can print them with php and they will be posted to your next php script.

Please note, that the user can change the values and you shouldn't trust them.

Also, you can consider using `$_SESSION`. That would be the better way to solve the task.

Please note that you shouldn't use `PHP_SELF` because it's insecure.

Comment: Thanks for your contribution.  I had wondered about $_SESSION, but for half of the solution I implemented, I fell back to a DB write/read; the other half involved MyStream sharing how to $_POST without using the HTML Form.  By the way, the project is a personal productivity tool; so not SO concerned about security in this instance; but if I eventually adapt it, I'll bone up on the insecurity you mentioned.  Again, thanks.